# How to insert Greek characters in MS-Access

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

Is there any way to insert greek letters into my database or reports in ms-access?
I don't want to change whole database font and I can't find "insert symbols" like excel and word for this purpose.

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/315684/how-to-use-special-characters-in-windows-documents

Comment: How exactly you perform the Insert ? ...

Answer (score 0):

As this is a programming forum, I assume you are using vba, so...

When I create a new form in Access, the default font is Calibri.
That unicode capbable font supports Greek characters.

To get a capital Greek letter Delta, in your code, put

```
txtControl = ChrW(916)
```

The ChrW() function inserts unicode characters into your text.
Change the number to get different letters.
Lower case letters start at 945.
I suspect that if you set your keyboard to Greek, it will allow you to just type in there...